# how to set UserTransaction Eclipselink/Glassfish in multitenancy web-app

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, multi-tenant, jta

i spend a lot of time arround this question my project deals with WEB-APP/multitenancy

- Eclipselink
- Glassfish v4.1
- Persistence Usage for Multiple Tenants : Persistence Unit per Tenant (according to eclipselink docs : [Persistence Usage for Multiple Tenants](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant)

the persistence.xml si set as follow :

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mydata</jta-data-source>

        <mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>

        <class>...</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-cache" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.exclude-eclipselink-orm" value="false"/>
            <property name="objectdb.query-language" value="JPA" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="5000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

inside a listener i put every new created EntityManagerFactory per tenant in a MAP and i call a static method to obtain an entity manager when needed

```
public static EntityManager createEntityManager(String tenant){

    if(mapEMF.containsKey(tenant)){
        return mapEMF.get(tenant).createEntityManager();
    }else{
        HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT, tenant);
        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_SHARED_EMF, "false");
        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_NAME, tenant);
        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CONNECTION_POOL_USER, "dbuser");
        properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CONNECTION_POOL_PASSWORD, "dbpass");

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, properties);

        mapEMF.put(tenant, emf);

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

my big question is how to obtain a transaction !

i have used but with no success

- @Resource UserTransaction trasaction;
- have created UserTransaction
  transaction = (UserTransaction)new
  InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
  with em.joinTransaction();

the only method that works is em.getTransaction.begin()/em.getTransaction.commit();

but according the API/docs getTransaction is used in RESOURCE_LOCAL witch is not recommended for java ee web-app where we are called to use JTA as transaction type

Please HELP.

Comment: By using Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory to create a new factory per tenant, it is outside the containers control.  I'm not sure you should be creating an EMF per tenant  (EclipseLink has multitenant options so tenants can share an EMF), but if you are, you might need to set other properties that the container might set for you, such as the target server.  See  https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_server.htm and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/GlassFishV3_Web_Tutorial

Comment: thx a lot @Chris, well, right, in case where we don't expect a specific business process for some tenants it will be convenient to set `MULTITENANT_SHARED_EMF to true`, but even with this config. i have experienced the same difficulties, for the moment i'll try with your suggestion : set `TargetServer to SunAS9` and use `@Ressource UserTransaction`